# Name for this Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

This is probably a very basic question, but I am asking because I could not find the answer online.

I have been trying to find out some properties regarding the following sum $$\sum_{n=0}^N\prod_{k=0}^na_k$$ When all the $a_n$'s are the same, this is the geometric sum, when $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, this is the partial sum of $e$. So this really seems to be something very important.

Is there a name for this sum?

Also, if there is(are) good reference(s) about this series, please be kind enough to mention about that. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure : sum product numbers

summation of product of numbers

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum-product_number

Comment: No, no, @HarishKayarohanam, my sum is different, please look at it again.

Comment: I feel like this is one of these questions where there is no (useful) answer because the series is far too general. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: Well, it's not Euler's constant -_-' ...I think this question is too general, since we don't know anything specific about the $a_{n}$ coefficients or the sequence of products $b_{n}=\prod^{n}_{k=0}a_{k}$...

Comment: You could study $b_n=\prod\limits_{k=0}^n a_k$ and then $\sum b_n$. Anyway, where did you get this series from?

Comment: Well, actually I think that I saw this series somewhere, but now I don't remember where I saw.